# How to calculate this series/with factorial in the numerator?

Tags: calculus

I'm wondering if anyone could help me out with figuring out this series?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{2^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

with the factorial in the bottom, what trick we need here to calculate it?

Thank you!!

Comment: Check out the Taylor series for the cosine

Comment: @imranfat, i see, thank you!! I'll look into it later~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{2^{2k}}{(2k)!}=\cosh 2 -1$ as shown by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20for%20cosh%28x%29) where the $-1$ comes because your sum starts from $k=1$ instead of $k=0$

Comment: Thank you!! Now I understand the solution on the book!!